# disable console output boost asio

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I want to use boost::asio http client example.

I removed all the std::cout from the code and still having print to the console.

How do I disable them?

Here is the output:

```
About to connect() to 172.16.7.201 port 5000 (#0)
*   Trying 172.16.7.201... * connected
* Connected to 172.16.7.201 (172.16.7.201) port 5000 (#0)
> GET /v2.0/ HTTP/1.1
Host: 172.16.7.201:5000
Accept: */*
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Tue, 11 Aug 2015 07:48:09 GMT
...
```

Here is the code, which is quite the same as the code from boost site without std::cout

```
Request(std::stringstream &pi_RequestStream , CrString pi_Host,CrString pi_port,std::stringstream & po_ssOutput)
{
try
{

    boost::asio::io_service io_service;

    // Get a list of endpoints corresponding to the server name.
    tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
    tcp::resolver::query query(pi_Host, pi_port);
    tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator = resolver.resolve(query);

    // Try each endpoint until we successfully establish a connection.
    tcp::socket socket(io_service);
    boost::asio::connect(socket, endpoint_iterator);

    // Form the request. We specify the "Connection: close" header so that the
    // server will close the socket after transmitting the response. This will
    // allow us to treat all data up until the EOF as the content.
    boost::asio::streambuf request;
    std::ostream request_stream(&request);
    request_stream << pi_RequestStream.str();


    // Send the request.
    boost::asio::write(socket, request);

    // Read the response status line. The response streambuf will automatically
    // grow to accommodate the entire line. The growth may be limited by passing
    // a maximum size to the streambuf constructor.
    boost::asio::streambuf response;
    boost::asio::read_until(socket, response, "\r\n");

    // Check that response is OK.
    std::istream response_stream(&response);
    std::string http_version;
    response_stream >> http_version;
    unsigned int status_code;
    response_stream >> status_code;
    std::string status_message;
    std::getline(response_stream, status_message);
    if (!response_stream || http_version.substr(0, 5) != "HTTP/")
    {
      return E_BADRESULT;
    }
    if (status_code != 200)
    {
      return E_FAIL;
    }

    // Read the response headers, which are terminated by a blank line.
    boost::asio::read_until(socket, response, "\r\n\r\n");

    // Process the response headers.
    std::string header;
    while (std::getline(response_stream, header) && header != "\r");

    // Write whatever content we already have to output.
    if (response.size() > 0)
        po_ssOutput<<&response;

    // Read until EOF, writing data to output as we go.
    boost::system::error_code error;
    while (boost::asio::read(socket, response,
          boost::asio::transfer_at_least(1), error))
        po_ssOutput<<&response;

    if (error != boost::asio::error::eof)
      throw boost::system::system_error(error);
}
catch (std::exception& e)
{
    //std::cout << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
    return E_FAIL;
}
return S_OK;
}
```

Comment: I think you forgot to rebuild app. boost::asio does not have such debug output.

Comment: You are right, i had a version with curlpp that is in debug mode